# ZGC and Xmx and vm.max_map_count

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection, zgc

We have a java 17 application which run with theses options:

```
-Xmx100g
-XX:+UseZGC
```

When running it, these gc warnings appear:

```
[warning][gc] 
***** WARNING! INCORRECT SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DETECTED! *****
The system limit on number of memory mappings per process might be too low for the given
max Java heap size (102400M). Please adjust /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count to allow for at
least 184320 mappings (current limit is 65530). Continuing execution with the current
limit could lead to a premature OutOfMemoryError being thrown, due to failure to map memory.
```

And after a few hours, by increasing heap usage (about ~ `60gb`), application encountered OOM and crashed.

Based on the above warning: `184320 = 1.8 * 102400`; Also i'v tried other `Xmx` values, the formula is:

`vm.max_map_count = 1.8 * xmx_in_mb`

My questions:

1. What is the relation of `ZGC` and `vm.max_map_count`? I can't find any official documentation about it!
2. Is it safe to use the above formula?

Comment: You asked almost the same question before? https://stackoverflow.com/q/75713808/1362755

Also... why not just try it and see whether it works?

Comment: Yes i've tried it. But no, its not the same question.

Comment: Point 1 "What is the relation of ZGC and vm.max_map_count?" and "my question is what exactly has been changed in java or GC which causes these warnings and eventually these errors?" ... are quite similar in my eyes. And the answer would be the same, ZGC simply needs more of that resource, that's their relation.
Also, how are big fat warning messages not documentation?